# Extra "Search web" appears when scrolling my site on iPhone

Tags: css, iphone, responsive-design, scroll

I am experiencing the following (strange) bug:

When my site is seen on iPhone 4 (haven't tested on 5), an extra "Search web" bar appears when scrolling up and down. It slows down the browsing dramatically. It happens on both Safari and Chrome. It doesn't happen on other sites on the same device (so it is not a problem with the phone itself or its browse).

I cannot find any similar reports on the internet.

Has anybody seen something like this?

Could you have a look at my site www.justrunlah.com and check if something is wrong?

Can you even reproduce it?

Screenshot: 
[image: Bug, an extra search bar appears]

thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding the search bar within your website (header-search) and see if the problem still exists (just to test to see if its your own searchbar that's causing the problem).

Comment: hi bigal, thanks. I did a search - It shouldn't come from that. One of the reasons is the text holder "Search web". This string does not appear anywhere in my project folder :/

Answer (score 0):

It was some sneaky code added by a plug-in.

More specifically: Sweet Captcha used a code connected to Errnio to monetize

I removed the plug in and it's gone

Read more: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/hidden-search-bar-features?replies=3